# How to configure HAProxy to route by port without using multiple frontend or listeners

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy

I am trying to configure Haproxy v1.5 for Jabber connections which run on several ports on the same IP.  To keep the configuration as simple as possible, I would like to use a single frontend and one or more backends.  Is there a way for me to pass the source port to the backend or to use a ACL to route to a different backend based on port?

```
frontend Jabber_IN
    bind 10.60.0.12:5222 name port5222
    bind 10.60.0.12:5223 name port5223
    bind 10.60.0.12:9090 name port9090
    bind 10.60.0.12:9091 name port9091
    bind 10.60.0.12:7070 name port7070
    bind 10.60.0.12:7443 name port7443
    bind 10.60.0.12:5229 name port5229 

    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option tcpka

    timeout client 60m
    timeout server 60m
    timeout http-keep-alive 1m

    default_backend Jabber

backend Jabber
     tcp-check connect
     tcp-check send PING\r\n
     tcp-check expect string +PONG
    server Server1ZoneD 10.60.30.209:80  check
    server Server1ZoneE 10.60.47.4:80    check
    server Server2ZoneD 10.60.17.8:80    check
    server Server2ZoneE 10.60.45.219:80  check
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using a single frontend and multiplexing to the backends is indeed possible. You will be required to add one backend section per backend server, e.g.

```
backend JabberD1
    tcp-check connect
    tcp-check send PING\r\n
    tcp-check expect string +PONG
    server Server1ZoneD 10.60.30.209:80  check

backend JabberE1
    tcp-check connect
    tcp-check send PING\r\n
    tcp-check expect string +PONG
    server Server1ZoneE 10.60.47.4:80    check
```

etc.

In your frontend, split the traffic like this

```
    acl d1 dst_port 5222
    use_backend JabberD1 if d1
```

etc.